# Delete the list in the list by specific value

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, data-manipulation

```
lists = [["a", 1], ["b", 2], ["c", 3]]
```

Is there a way to delete the list in the list by a specific value?

For example, I would like to delete the list ["b", 2] by indicating delete the list which contains 2.

Comment: I think use a dict here instead list is a good idea. For example: `the_dict = {"1": "a", "2": "b", "3": "c"}`, then you can delete the value by key like `the_dict.pop('2')`.

Comment: @KevinGuan Yours worked for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a list comprehension to exclude the members you are not interested in.

```
>>> lists = [["a", 1], ["b", 2], ["c", 3]]
>>> [i for i in lists if 2 not in i]
[['a', 1], ['c', 3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lists = [["a", 1], ["b", 2], ["c", 3]]
lists1 = []

def check_if_two(r):
   if 2 not in r:
     lists1.append(r)

for s in lists:
   check_if_two(s)

print lists1
```

Comment: This answer is fine, but the accepted answer should be @AvinashRaj 's. Much more pythonic, and much better performance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go through the whole list, and search after the list you want to delete. A list is like an array. If you want something you have to search after it. So the question is now how to do this right?

Try this:

```
indexNumber := ["foo", "bar", "baz"].index('bar')
```

You will get the index. And with the index you can delete it with pop(indexNumber). This would work if you know the whole list you search. But this is not what you want. What you need is this:

```
#Create a copy of your list
listOfThings = list(lists);
counter = 0;

#Look at each list in your list
for aList in listOfThings
  if -1 != aList.index("what you want")
    lists.pop(counter);
  counter += 1;
```

This code is untested, but I think it will help you a little bit. And I hope I haven't mixed too many programming languages.